# DataGridViewAutoFilter Ignores culture and shows filters in chinese on Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using [DataGridViewAutoFilter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataGridViewAutoFilter/) and for some reasons it completely ignores my current application language settings. I tried forcing a culture on my main form constructor just after `InitializeComponent()`, like so:

```
        InitializeComponent()

        CultureInfo culture;
        culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

I have no clue to what to look for in order to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: The library has hard-coded strings and logic based on those strings.

Comment: Just use this instead: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290586/FilterableDataGridView-Csharp-NET-A-DataGridView-c

Comment: great suggestions , thanks! as soon as I'm able I'll go  through  this topic and give the due attention !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your culture setting is ignored is simple. The library author has decided to hard code his Chinese text.

Take a look inside the `private void PopulateFilters()` method and you will find subsequent code:

```
filters.Insert(0, "(全部)", null);
filters.Insert(0, "(自定义)", null);
```

You can verify yourself by decompiling the nuget package.  The library author needs to change his code in order to make it work for international users.

Answer (score 1):

Introducing **DataGridView-AutoFilter** [Nuget Package version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataGridView-AutoFilter) with a detailed [article](https://anynomous.medium.com/datagridview-autofilter-621f80f71b63).

Comment: @Talha does this help?